# POSIX message queue - Does it still exists after reboot?

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

On linux, wrote a simple program to create a POSIX message queue, and send a msg to it, after the process terminated, it seems the msg is still there.

**The questions are:**

- Does the msg still there after reboot?
- If it exists, then it's on disk, how did it guarantee the performance if it stores msg on disk instead of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, message queues are mounted on a *virtual* file system, and the presence of a file does not imply that anything is written to physical media.  This implementation is specific to Linux and not required POSIX behaviour.

The [mq_overview](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) man page describes the implementation.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's implemented similar as `virtual memory file system`.

Comment: @EricWang : I believe that the queue itself is in memory as essentially  a *memory mapped file*, but the file-system on which the file exists is itself entirely in memory - which may in turn I suppose get swapped to the system swap file.   I am guessing here, but the upshot is that nothing is written to disk and any "files" left by the queue are temporary.  Moreover of course that may not be true for other POSIX implementations, that is just the Linux implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get enough info to understand the concept, the actual implementation don't matters much I guess.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't exist after reboot, since it resides on a [virtual filesystem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html).

Comment: OK, I saw the link mentioned it has `Kernel Persistence`. Means if not removed by `mq_unlink()`, then it will exists in kernel until system shutdown.

Comment: But I don't think `virtual file system` is the reason cause that, because all(at least most) regular files exists on VFS, I guess.

Comment: @EricWang : *A* VFS, not *the* VFS. Virtualising a file system does not imply identical behaviour. The regular file system commits files to physical media, others map to devices, the mq is similar to a RAM disk.